# How can I replace every letter in a string with something else? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have to develop a hangman game as part of a school assignment, and I'm trying to create a new string that will output the word to be guessed as just stars. e.g hello would be ****. Below is the code I have tried, the output seems to be only the last letter of the string to be replaced with a star, but the rest of the string is seemingly untouched:

```
word_to_guess = input("Enter a word for player 2 to guess:")

def guess_the_word(word_to_guess):
    for letter in word_to_guess:
        number_of_letters = word_to_guess.replace(letter, '*')    #Taking the original string and replacing each letter with a star, giving player 2 an indicator of how many letters there are to guess
    print("{} is the word for today".format(number_of_letters))
```

Any pointers as to where I went wrong will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try

```py
'*' * len(word_to_guess)
```

which will multiply the `*` with the length of `word_to_guess`.

Comment: This is the optimal solution, I'll leave my answer for explanation of what's going on

Comment: Thanks, this works :)

Comment: I've done the same, @C.Nivs.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the output of `word_to_guess.replace`, so each time it's for a single operation:

```py
word = 'hello'

output = word.replace('h', '*')
# *ello

output = word.replace('e', '*')
# h*llo

# and so on
```

You probably just need

```py
def guess_the_word(word):
    letters = ''

    for char in word:
        letters += '*'

    print(letters)
```

Or

```py
def word_to_guess(word):
    return ''.join('*' for char in word)
```

Answer (score -1):

A better way to get a hashed version the same length as the word may be by using the length property.

**Example:**

```py
word = "sponge"
hashedWord = ''

hashedWord += '#'*len(word)
print(f"Hashed word: {hashedWord}")
```

**Output:**

```py
Hashed word: ######
```